# Test data generation framework in python?

Tags: python, testing, test-data, data-generation

Is there any "test-data" generation framework out there, specially for Python?

To make it clear, instead of writing scripts from scratch that fill my database with random users and other entities I want to know if there are any tools/frameworks out there to make it easier,

To make it even more clear, I am not looking for test frameworks, I want to generate test data to "put some load" my application.

Comment: Given that what "data" consists of varies widely from app to app... probably not.

Comment: but you know, there are lots of tools that inspect the data structures and database design and generate code for to do something with that, there should be something out there!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/fake-data-generator/
Looks like what you want. I tend to just use ranges with appropriate upper and lower limits and liberal use of lists.
If you need your test data to match the distribution of your population then you'll need to do more work though.

Comment: https://github.com/joke2k/faker

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to write any code, try [Mockaroo](http://mockaroo.com). It's a free web app that allows you to generate random test data tables in lots of different formats such as XML, JSON, Excel, CSV. You are allowed to generate up to 1000 rows for free.